# Parse Json Response and insert into oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to oracle and facing a little challenge in iterating through a json response.
I know there are many examples online which work on json array element and then insert, but i tried various things and couldnt get this to work.

The json response is like this:

```
{
    'data':
         {
           'Key_one' : 'value_one',
           'Key_two' : 'value_two'
         }
}
```

I have a stored proc:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST(JSON_TEXT_DATA) AS
BEGIN
---- need a for loop here to dynamically iterate and insert. 
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME('KEY_ONE') values(json_value(JSON_TEXT_DATA,'$.data.Key_One'));
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME('KEY_TWO') values(json_value(JSON_TEXT_DATA,'$.data.Key_Two'));
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JSON_TABLE to insert the values into your table. Using this method will put both keys into a single row in your table.

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (key_one, key_two)
    SELECT key1, key2
      FROM JSON_TABLE ('{
    "data":
         {
           "Key_one" : "value_one",
           "Key_two" : "value_two"
         }
}',
                       '$.data'
                       COLUMNS key1 VARCHAR2 PATH '$.Key_one', key2 VARCHAR2 PATH '$.Key_two');
```

Comment: The problem is there are around 30-40 such keys and i was wondering if i could do this without explicitly specifying the json path. thats why i am looking for a for-loop kinda solution

Comment: It is possible to build an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement for your table based on the JSON keys, but it would require SQL sanitization, bind variables, and looping. Using the method provided above may take a bit more time for writing the initial statement, but does not require any of those methods for a dynamic solution and will likely be the most performant since it is a pure SQL solution.